# useRef hook to keep focus on Antd input

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

I'm trying to make a custom editable table using `antd` `<Table>, <Form>` and `<Input>` within stateless functional component wrapped into `Form.create()()`.

At the moment, whenever I type in single character into `<Input>` or move mouse the field loses focus.

I tried to keep focus, on the `<Input>` by using:

```
const inputEl = useRef(null);
...
<Input
  ref={inputEl}
  onChange={()=> {inputEl.current.focus()}}
/>
```

but that doesn't work, because you can't `focus()` on `<Input>`.

Is there any way to get this working?

UPDATE: here's `inputRef`
[image]

Comment: You need to provide a producible example: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), also, I made an example in my answer which shows that it works, no one can guess the state on your specific machine/project.

Comment: @DennisVash Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do - is to get your example as close to my situation as possible

Comment: So create a MINIMAL sandbox like I did.

Answer (score 1):

You assuming that `Input` reference has `focus` function of `input`, but actually as it is an implementation of `input` it holds the right reference within `input` object:

```
inputEl.current.input.focus
```

For every custom component, you can't assume that it even has any kind of reference, it depends on the implementation.

```
const inputEl = useRef();
...
<Input
  ref={inputEl}
  onChange={()=> {inputEl.current.input.focus()}}
/>
```

```
const App = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = useState(DEFAULT_INITIAL);
  const onChange = e => {
    setValue(e.target.value);
    console.log(inputEl.current.input.focus);
  };
  const inputEl = useRef();
  return (
    <FlexBox>
      <Input ref={inputEl} value={value} onChange={onChange} />
    </FlexBox>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Q-58993884-inputFocus]

> Side note: if you using `Form.create` with `getFieldDecorator`, you should **avoid** using `onChange`, yon can read it [in detail at related docs.](https://ant.design/components/form/)

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that too, but it doesn't work. There's no such method as focus() in current.input

Comment: Check the example